# JasperReports fill new page with same type of data

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports and I would like to generate charts for different objects from same POJO class. POJO Class looks like below:

```
public class POJOClass{
private Double value;
private long timestamp; //constructor+getters
```

What do I want to do?

- In first step I would like to fill chart from value of first object.
- Then I would like to add next page and go into second step of loop,
  get from database next object and fill chart in 2nd page.

I am using same POJO however both objects has different value. The problem is that I can fill only one page.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        List<POJOClass> pojoDescribtions= new ArrayList<>(); //add some result into List
        JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(pojoDescribtions);
        parameterMap.put("datasource", jrDataSource);

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameterMap, jrDataSource);

}
```

It always create chart for 2nd step and I do not know how to get also for the first one.

Comment: I think you've got your answer [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1088066/how-fill-new-page-same-type-data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similary problem.

- Instead of List of POJOClass prepare List of Lists of POJO. It helps you to distinguish one object from another.
- Create List of JasperPrints
- Create for loop
- Inside of loop create JRBeanCollection, put it to parameterMap and create new jasper print which put into list.
- You can return List of JasperPrints and it will works fine.

  `List<List<POJOClass>> pojoList = new ArrayList<List<POJOClas>>();
  Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
  List<JasperPrint> jasperPrints = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
  JRDataSource jrDataSource;
  JasperPrint jasperPrint;`

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<pojoList.size(); i++){
          jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(pojoList.get(i));
          parameterMap.put("dataSource", pojoList.get(i));
          jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameterMap, jrDataSource);
          jasperPrints.add(jasperPrint);
      }
  ```

At the end you have to simple export it by Exporter